# Nginx + PHP-FPM Using CPU and Not RAM

Tags: php, optimization, nginx

I am doing load testing on an Nginx Server and I am having an issue where my CPU hits 100% but only 50% of my ram is being utilized. The server is this:

```
2 vCPU
2 GB of RAM
40GB SSD Drive
Rackspace High Performance Server
```

This is my Nginx Config

```
worker_processes  2;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1524;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include   /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    access_log off;

    # Sendfile copies data between one FD and other from within the kernel.
    # More efficient than read() + write(), since the requires transferring data to and from the user space.
    sendfile on;

    # Tcp_nopush causes nginx to attempt to send its HTTP response head in one packet,
    # instead of using partial frames. This is useful for prepending headers before calling sendfile,
    # or for throughput optimization.
    tcp_nopush on;

    # don't buffer data-sends (disable Nagle algorithm). Good for sending frequent small bursts of data in real time.
    tcp_nodelay on;

    # allow the server to close the connection after a client stops responding. Frees up socket-associated memory.
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # send the client a "request timed out" if the body is not loaded by this time. Default 60.
    client_body_timeout 10;

    # If the client stops reading data, free up the stale client connection after this much time. Default 60.
    send_timeout 2;

    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    gzip  on;
    server_tokens off;

    client_max_body_size 20m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

client_max_body_size 20m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf

    fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m max_size=1000m inactive=60m;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

Kernal additions in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
# Increase system IP port limits to allow for more connections

net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 2000 65000


net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1


# number of packets to keep in backlog before the kernel starts dropping them
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 3240000


# increase socket listen backlog
net.core.somaxconn = 3240000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000


# Increase TCP buffer sizes
net.core.rmem_default = 8388608
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic
```

Example VHost Config with PHP-FPM

```
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name  www.example.com;

    location / {
        root   /data/sites/example.com/public_html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?rt=$uri&$args;
    }

   location ~ \.php {
      root          /data/sites/example.com/public_html;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param ENV production;
      include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The server can handle about 60 active SBU connections clicking around, or about 300 request per second. Is the fact that is not fully utilizing RAM and more CPU a bad thing? Can I optimize this further?

Comment: Try and see - it varys on application. In general if you cache something (will use more ram) it will help the CPU by not having to calculate it again. It will vary by your usage though

Comment: What kind of application are you running?